# (not set) grouping in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm working with Google Analytics and i've come across a (not set) issue with Content Grouping. I changed my URL's in the month of August, and then most of the URL's went into the (not set) Content Grouping, instead of its specific group. Is there anything I can do to have the URL's put back into their correct grouping?

Also, i'm reporting out this data  via Data Studio and I was wondering if there was a query/filter that I could use to have it be grouped into the correct content grouping?

Answer (score 0):

The content groupings you have probably was dependent on the URL. You will need to [modify your existing content groupings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167) in GA and change the rules so that it matches the new URLs.

As for reporting in DataStudio, you can use [CASE functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en) in a new calculated field. The cases will be the rules for your content groupings. Example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(page, "(mypagepath1|mypagepath2|mypagepath3)") THEN "Group 1" 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(page, "(mypagepath4|mypagepath5)" ) THEN "Group 2" 
    ELSE "No Group" 
END
```

After that you will use the new calculated field in place of the content grouping dimension.

Comment: Once I saw that my content grouping/reporting wasn't coming out correct, I went ahead and reverted the URL change that I made back, so that's why just my August data is in that (not set) category. Is there a way to have just that one month of data be modified for it to go into the correct content grouping?

Comment: No, once the data is in GA, you cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As @Sonali has already implied, you need to take into account the fact that GA is incapable of setting an 'if not set, use default' value on a dimension. If you can see any way of better interpreting the August data you do have, try using the GA plugin in Google Sheets: if you do that, and then use a Sheets formula to manipulate the data, you can then have GDS access the sheet.

Comment: I've grabbed all of the data and put it into Google Sheets, but i'm having a hard time on what to do next. I have the page path of all of the (not set) data, but they need to be put into the various Content Groups? Do I use a vlookup formula to match specific page paths into the Content Groups?

Comment: You'll have to experiment. I'm sure that vlookup, and probably some sort of lookup table to translate between page paths and content groups, will have roles to play.